# Jquery get index of same type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how to get the index of a figure tag inside a particular wrapper relative to that wrapper. I've prepared an exemple here: http://jsfiddle.net/vhyfwbjm/ (or see below)

The wrapper `#wrapper` contains three `figure` tags differently nested. I would like to get the `index()` relative to `#wrapper`.

Any ideas ?

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>
        <figure>
            <img src="#" />
        </figure>
        <div class="another-wrapper">
            <figure>
                <img src="#" />
            </figure>
            <div class="another-wrapper">
                <figure>
                    <img src="#" />
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Always put the relevant code and markup **in** the question, not just linked (not even when it's jsFiddle). *(I've done it for you this time.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply ask for the index inside `#wrapper`:

```
$('figure').on('click', function() {
    console.log( $('#wrapper').find('figure').index( this ) );
});
```

You select the collection of elements you want to look through (`.find('figure')`) then ask for the index of a specific element (`this` refers to the clicked `figure`, here).

You can also pass in another jQuery selector as your index-element:

```
<figure id="myFigure"></figure>
...
console.log( $('#wrapper').find('figure').index( $('#myFigure') ) );
```

Comment: No worries - any chance of an upvote and marked as correct? :) The other guys probably deserve an upvote too, their answers are also correct, even if they weren't the answers you looked at :-)

Comment: You're right. Because i'm new to this forum i'm not able to upvote because of my lack of reputation ;-)

Comment: Thanks dear, "$('#wrapper').find('figure').index( this )" is very simplest solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Find all the `figure` tag inside wrapper and iterate them.

```
$(function(){
    $('#wrapper').find('figure').each(function(index){
     alert(index);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/vhyfwbjm/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.index()` with parameter. Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$("figure").click(function(){
var figureElements=$("#wrapper").find("figure");
    alert(figureElements.index(this));
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vhyfwbjm/3/)